# setting NSAttributed String attribute overrides substring attributes

Tags: objective-c, nsattributedstring

I have created a mutable string  which will look like @"**testMeIn:greenColor:Different:greencolor:Colors**"

```
NSMutableAttributedString *mutableText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:myString];

UIColor *foregroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
NSString *key = NSForegroundColorAttributeName;

[mutableText addAttribute:key value:foregroundColor range:NSMakeRange(0, myString.length)];
```

When I add Attribute foregroundColor , the existing green color in substring gets overridden by the specified black color. Though I can change the code to set the green color for substring, I would like to know is there any other way of applying styles to the part of Strings which doesn't have styles without overriding the existing styles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can enumerate over each attribute span in the string, and only change attributes if they are not already set

```
 NSMutableAttributedString* aString = 
 [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"testMeIn DIFFERENT Colors"];

 [aString setAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor greenColor]} 
                  range:(NSRange){9,9}];

 [aString enumerateAttributesInRange:(NSRange){0,aString.length}
                             options:nil
                          usingBlock:
     ^(NSDictionary* attrs, NSRange range, BOOL *stop) {

          //unspecific: don't change text color if ANY attributes are set
         if ([[attrs allKeys] count]==0)
             [aString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName 
                             value:[UIColor redColor] 
                             range:range];

         //specific: don't change text color if text color attribute is already set
         if (![[attrs allKeys] containsObject:NSForegroundColorAttributeName])
             [aString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName 
                             value:[UIColor redColor] 
                             range:range];
     }];
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this should work. 

But am afraid, it may become a costly operation when styles are changed frequently. and distinct styles are added in a lengthy string.